# Switch port with multiple devices

Tags: cisco, switch

I understand that each port of a legacy switch can be connected to a device via ethernet cable. Thus, it is possible that one port can have multiple devices? This is because in SDN, this thing is possible since you can program it but I don't know if it is applicable in traditional networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question.

You could have a hub or another switch connected to a switch port, and the traffic from many devices could come through a single switch port, especially if the switch is a root bridge.

Comment: So I can have a hub that joins multiple PCs and this hub is connected to a single switch port, right?

Comment: Yes. A hub or a switch will have frames from multiple, sometimes hundreds, of devices coming into the switch port.

Comment: Does it make a collision?

Comment: There can be collisions on the link if it is configured for half-duplex, which is required for hub connections, but not for connection to a switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add multiple devices to your network, I suggest to use Switch instead of HUB, switches have been invented to resolve many problems caused by HUB like "**one single big collision domain, one big broadcast domain, speed/duplex limitation and so on**". even with Switch sometimes it is necessary to create **smaller broadcast domain** wich is good for network performance by using vlan. so avoid using hub in your network if you can afford switch.